# Как умножить значение которое прислал пользователь в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

После строки

```
bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Напишите количество подписчиков?")
```

Пользователь отправляет (к примеру) 10, и бот должен умножить сообщение пользователя на 2
Буду очень благодарен за ответ!!!

```
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            elif call.data=="another":
                bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Напишите количество подписчиков?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переделал ваш код.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("ext", callback_data="another"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "asd", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'another')
def callback_inline(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Напишите количество подписчиков?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, subscriber_input)


def subscriber_input(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{int(message.text)*2}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "вы ввели не число")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, subscriber_input)
```

Пример.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!